# What kind of impact the word 'yet' has on the sentence?

Tags: polarity-items

What kind of **impact the word 'yet' has** on the sentence or is there no impact at all and **can we even omit 'yet'** without losing the meaning (context) of the sentence?

> Current version includes a range of new features and functions to give you the best experience **yet**.

Comment: In your context, ***yet*** means *up until now* (this experience will be better than any previous ones). Without it, you might just end up with *the best experience you could hope for* from such a complex and hard-to-configure bit of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,

> yet

is used a a kind of intensifier to say that the experience is the best you could have when compared to any of your experiences in the *past*.

*Yet* means up until now in your usage.  The shortened form might be

> This is the best **yet**!

meaning, *this is the best up until now*.

> Player A was able to make the semifinals of this tournament. He has not been able to get past the first round of any tournament before, it is his best showing **yet**.